# Nodejs - superagent-http-signature - signature not sent

Tags: node.js, http-signature

I'm using [this site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent-http-signature)

```
var superagent = require('superagent');
var superagentHttpSignature = require('superagent-http-signature');

superagent
    .get('http://project.dev/api/v3/project/tasks/get?task_id=1026')
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .set('x-app-key', 'MY_ACCESS_KEY')
    .set('x-app-trusted', 'key=None')
    .use(superagentHttpSignature({
        headers: ['(request-target)', 'Accept', 'x-app-key', 'x-app-trusted'],
        algorithm: 'hmac-sha256',
        key: 'MY_ACCESS_KEY',
        keyId: 'MY_SECRET_KEY'
    }))
    .end(function(err, res) {
        // console.log(err);
        console.log(res.body);
    });
```

Node version: `v4.2.1`

If I inspect the signature header on the server (running PHP by the way, with its own signature verifier, using the same specifications) the signature header is missing.

Anything I am missing? Or are there any alternative node packages with same feature?

My purpose of this is to be able to call the API using other language aside from PHP as proof of concept so I could later use this into AWS Lambda scheduled task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works and the bug is on your server side. Maybe something between PHP and the code (Apache? nginx?) is filtering the headers.

```
GET /api/v3/project/tasks/get?task_id=1026 HTTP/1.1
Host: project.dev
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: node-superagent/1.8.0-beta.2
Accept: application/json
x-app-key: MY_ACCESS_KEY
x-app-trusted: key=None
Authorization: Signature keyId="MY_SECRET_KEY",algorithm="hmac-sha256",headers="(request-target) Accept x-app-key x-app-trusted",signature="9ietyIsW8nPH6BqwiePqsDefQpGUFERoV7wEaQ9UUGQ="
Connection: close
```

Comment: I see. I'll check the server configuration.How do you review the headers? Sorry, node fluent with nodejs.

Comment: I just put up netcat as a server, to get the request from the client. `nc -l <port>`, and then connect to that with `http://<server>:<port>/api/v3/project/tasks/get?task_id=1026`, but there are many ways to do it.

Comment: Just tested it and indeed the Authorization header is present. The header is probably stripped in nginx (proxy) or in Apache inside my Docker container. However, the `keyId="SECRET_KEY"` part seems wrong, it should be the access key. Anyway, it seems that this package is not compatible with my API server. I'll probably just write my own implementation or find another package. Thanks! Marking as answer.